# Scale content with size of menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, scale

I was trying something out as a test but didn't quite know how to program it the right way. I was hoping someone could help me out with that.

I made a sketch so it would be a little more clear about what I want to achieve. The menu on the left needs to stay in that exact position.

[image]

Let's say the content next to the menu would be smaller than the menu itself. Then the green sections would go underneath the menu. This is not what I want to achieve. I was thinking about scaling the height of the content with Javascript if the content element is too small.

Do you feel like this is the right way to accomplish the desired result? Or could you suggest a better/cleaner way to accomplish this? (An example on jsfiddle would be great)

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I would also like to inform that the menu's height needs to be dynamic. For example what if I add an extra menu item.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: How about `min-height:321px;`?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

Just be wary this Only works on MODERN browsers as I am using the checkbox hack :)

Here is a code snipet

```css
*{
 box-sizing:border-box;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}

#head{
 background-color:#000;
 border-bottom:#333 solid 1px;
 display:block;
 padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;
}
#head ul{
 background-color:#f00;
 display:block;
 width:150px;
 position:relative;
 list-style:none;
 margin:0px;
 text-align:center;
}
#head li{
 display:none;
}
#head input{
 display:none;
}
#head input:checked ~ li{
 display:block;
}
#head input:checked ~ label{
 background-color:#511;
 color:#fff;
}
#head label{
 font-family:Constantia;
 width:100%;
 padding:10px 0px;
 color:#333;
 border-bottom:#111 dotted 1px;
 display:block;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}
#head label:hover{
 background-color:#511;
 color:#fff;
 cursor:pointer;
}
#head a:link{
 background-color:#f00;
 width:150px;
 display:block;
 color:#111;
 text-decoration:none;
 border-bottom:#333 solid 1px;
 padding:10px;
 float:left;
 margin-right:10px;
}
#head a:visited{
 color:#111;
}
#head a:hover{
 background-color:#911;
 color:#fff;
 border-bottom:#211 solid 1px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
#body{
 padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">
   <ul>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu" />
    <label for="menu">Menu</label>
    
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div id="body">
   <h1>Content</h1>
   <p> All my content sits here what am I suppose to do?</p>
  </div>
```

By making use of floats rather than position absolute lets the browser know there is suppose to be content under the header if I had to change it to apply position absolute it would still go out the header but won't take up any space therfore the content wont shift next to or under it but rather behind the navigation.

You should see that the content will go below it when the window gets smaller if you wish to make the content not be squashed up a bit before going underneath the navigation is to set a `min-width` to the `#body{}` tag.